# RTK Prevent matchFulfilled from being called if there is a more recent request

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am working on an web app with multiple cards. When a card is selected some data will be loaded on a map.
Some cards might load slower than other (for some of them there is more data and more calculations involved).

The issue is that if a card with more data is selected, and afterwards the user selects another card with less data (while the request for the first one is still loading) there might be situations where the request for the second card loads faster than the first one.
So basically the data for the second card one is loaded for a short time on the map, and afterwards, when the first request also finishes loading, the data on the map replaced with information from the first card (even tough the second one is the current selected one).

I tried aborting the request when another one is fired. Something like:

```
const req = getCardData(id)
...
req.abort()
```

But the request still finishes normally and `getCardData.matchFulfilled` is still called.

I thought about trying to check if the data loaded is for the current selected card, but this is really problematic especially since it can happen for different requests (the card loading part might happen in different parts of the app and some additional requests might get triggered after the first one is done).

Also I might not have the data available for all of them because some of the request are calculated of FE side and for those I don't really have the id available. Making it available would require quite some work and just storing and passing over a lot of functions and components an id for the sole purpose of checking if the last request response is the last triggered, so I'd really like another approach if there is any.

I also read [this question (and answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870135/how-to-cancel-the-rtk-query-requests) as well as [this github issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3218) but it doesn't seem to give a good option for a lazy query. I am open to other alternatives if aborting isn't an option, but I would appreciate a generic one (if possible)

Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to a conclusion on github with a some help. Ended up using something like:

```
let lastRequestId: number
export const mySlice = createSlice({
  ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(myApi.endpoints.getData.matchPending, (state, action) => {
      lastRequestId = action.meta.requestId
    })
    builder.addMatcher(myApi.endpoints.getData.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
       if(lastRequestId == action.meta.requestId)  {
         ...
       }
    })
```

For reference [here is the discussion on github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/3218)

---

Another option might be to use your state to check if the request is the one you wanted.

For example let's say you have a list of movies, `selectedMovie` in your state and you requested the list of movies for selectedMovie.id (something like `getMoovies(moovie.id)` ).

For this case you can do something like:

```
export const mySlice = createSlice({
  ...
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(myApi.endpoints.getData.matchPending, (state, action) => {
      // originalArgs are arguments passed to the query
        const requestId = Number(action.meta.arg.originalArgs)
        if (state.selectedMoovie.id === requestId) {
          // only update the state in this case
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
})
```

For additional information on RTK useQuerry args (and how to use originalArgs) you can check [RTK useQuerry docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery)

Comment: You can chain requests inside transformResponse. I think you're really making this too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [RTK Query](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics)? It maintains a cache, and the hook that's part of what's currently displayed on the screen will point to the cache entry that matches the query criteria that were called for it (in your case, the id). You can do your post-processing in [transformResponse](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#transforming-responses).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I am using RTK Querry. But my issue is that there might be two requests that are resolved in the the reversed order they are triggered. And therefore, the in the matchFulfilled matcher (triggered in my slice) the data stored in my redux tookit store might be different from the last one requested. I am however coming close to a decent solution imo (using `matchPending` and `action.meta.requestId`)

Comment: If you're using the hook, it should literally just be bound to the id of the card and you shouldn't need to do this. I think you're making it too hard.

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet on how you would treat this problem with transformResponse ? Considering you have a function getData which is triggered onClick and you need to update the state and also make sure that only the last triggered request is considered. Thank you!

Comment: That's hard without knowing what transformations you're doing in matchFulfilled, but whatever you're doing there you'd just move it into transformResponse so the endpoint data is just whatever you're changing it to in matchFulfilled. If you need both, you could create an object with original and transformed properties.

Comment: But my response formatting is not my issue! I am not talking anywhere about formatting my response. I don't know how to explain this any better, but I did found my solution and it has nothing to do with transforming the respose

Comment: The issue from this question was only the order in which requests to the same endpoint (but with different param id) are resolved . And if the order some are resolved is different from the order they are triggered, how to make sure that only the last triggered one affects a slice state (and ignore the others that were triggered earlier but resolved later than the last request)

Comment: Yes, but you're making it too complicated. If you use the endpoint as it's designed and just bind to the transformed result, you won't need to care about all that. Instead of putting all this in another slice and contorting yourself to make that work, just use RTK Query for what it's good at.

Comment: This is not another slice. And sorry, but your are not making any sense to me. I am using the endpoint exactly for what it was designed to do, and I do need to worry about that. And I do tend to think that, since the RTK co-maintaner approved this approach, it can't be that bad or overcomplicated.

Comment: The api slice by default is not the same slice as any other slice in your app, and you don't need extraReducers for it because you have transformResponse.